# Determining if user installed app from an ad link

Tags: ios, app-store, hyperlink, ads

I'd like to be able to connect the dots on whether a user has installed and subsequently launched my app after viewing advert either through another iOS app or a website.

Is there anything to specify with the app store URL which carries over into the app's launch?

What are the general practices of trying to doing this?

Applies to iOS 4.0+

Comment: It is actually called as conversion rate. You can get those stats from your ad network provider. Just ask how many of the impressions converted in an ad campaign that you launched. Not sure if this is what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: Can the app store pass any information to the app after install? That is, find out what led the user to go to the App store and download the app and then later, launched the app?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Apsalar](https://apsalar.com/) . They use several methods like UUID, IDFA tracking etc to determine the source of app install (Provided you use their custom download links in your Campaigns)

Note: This requires you to either install their SDK in the app or configure server to server tracking.

They also provide some cool analytics data. You can do a cohort analysis in conjunction with your campaign source, to measure which source is performing the best.

All of the above requires to be set up  within the app. Refer documentation on their site.

We are using Apsalar for our [Project Management app](http://www.planningproapp.com/)

Comment: Note that Apple is now advising against accessing IDFA in apps that don't have ads: https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-iphone/issues/109